# A question about the concept of tangent plane from William Wade's book

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

This question is from William Wade's book 11.6.9 page: 435.

I have the book's solution manual. That's, I have the question's answer. But, the answer is complicated accourding to me. I dont understand it how to solve. And so, i cannot write any idea about that question.sorry:( Please, I Will be happy to explain the two parts. Thank you :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a distinction between what you **define** and what you **prove**: this depends on the approach you are using.
I have not Wade's book within reach, but I can tell you how the matter is approached usually.
You **define** the tangent plane 
as the plane passing through the point $(a,b,c)$ and perpendicular to the vector $\nabla F(a,b,c)$, after **proving** that $\nabla F(a,b,c)$ is perpendicular to the tangent line in $(a,b,c)$ to *every* curve on $G$ that passes through $(a,b,c)$: this is a *reasonable* (or *natural*) definition as it must be in mathematics.
In this context the crucial tool is the chain rule.
If a curve is given by the vector $(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ with $(x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t_0))=(a,b,c)$, then the same curve is on $G$ if $$F(x(t),y(t),z(t))=0$$ that, differentiated by the chain rule, gives $$\nabla F \,(x(t),y(t),z(t)) \cdot (x'(t),y'(t),z'(t)) =0$$ in particular $$\nabla F \, (a,b,c) \cdot (x'(t_0),y'(t_0),z'(t_0)) =0$$ The latter shows the above thesis.
Of course all this requires some "smoothness" for $F$ (for example *continuous differentiability*).